# SonarQube showing 0% coverage for Unit Test in a NodeJS appliication

Tags: sonarqube

On SonarQube server, for all my projects, the scans are happening and I can see the Sonar metrics but the Unit Test coverage is showing as 0% for both 'new code' and 'overall code'.

The project source code is written in NodeJS/JavaScript which I need to scan with SonarQube.

Please refer attached screenshot:-

[image]
[image]

Package.json:-

```
    {
  "name": "analytics",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Microservice to handle CRUD operations of analytics",
  "main": "server.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node -r dotenv/config server.js",
    "dev:watch": "nodemon --watch ../analytics --watch ../../common -r dotenv/config server.js",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "nyc --reporter=lcov --reporter=text-lcov mocha -r dotenv/config" 
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.752.0",
    "aws-xray-sdk": "^2.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bcrypt": "3.0.8",
    "body-parser": "1.19.0",
    "cls-hooked": "4.2.2",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "express-mung": "^0.5.1",
    "express-useragent": "^1.0.13",
    "fast-csv": "^4.1.3",
    "json2csv": "^5.0.5",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "kafka-node": "^5.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.5",
    "passport-saml": "1.3.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pg": "7.14.0",
    "pg-hstore": "2.3.3",
    "prom-client": "12.0.0",
    "prometheus-api-metrics": "2.2.3",
    "qrcode": "1.4.4",
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "redis-clustr": "1.7.0",
    "seedrandom": "^3.0.5",
    "sequelize": "5.21.2",
    "speakeasy": "2.0.0",
    "streamifier": "^0.1.1",
    "uuid": "3.3.3",
    "winston": "3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "6.10.2",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "chai-http": "4.3.0",
    "chai-jest-snapshot": "^2.0.0",
    "chai-uuid": "1.0.6",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "mocha": "6.2.2",
    "mochawesome": "4.1.0",
    "nyc": "14.1.1",
    "redis-mock": "0.49.0",
    "sequelize-mock": "0.10.2",
    "sinon": "7.5.0"
  }
}
```

Jenkinsfile code snippet:-

```
    stages{
            
            stage('Lint Analysis'){
                steps{
                    echo '*************running lint analysis**********'
                    // sh 'eslint . --ext .js -c .eslintrc.js --fix || true'    //To display output on console
                    // sh 'eslint . --ext .js -c .eslintrc.js --fix -f checkstyle > eslint.xml || true' //To create report which will be use by checkstyle plugin
                }
            }
        
            stage('Unit Test'){
                steps{
                    //Running Unit test to get Code Coverage report using clover plugin
                    dir('services/analytics') { 
                            echo '************ Running UT ***********'                  
                            // sh 'npm install'
                            // sh 'npm run coverage'
                            // step([
                            //  $class: 'CloverPublisher',
                            //  cloverReportDir: 'test/coverage',
                            //  cloverReportFileName: 'clover.xml',
                            //  healthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 80, conditionalCoverage: 80, statementCoverage: 80], 
                            //  unhealthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 50, conditionalCoverage: 50, statementCoverage: 50], 
                            //  failingTarget: [methodCoverage: 0, conditionalCoverage: 0, statementCoverage: 0]     
                            // ])
                    }
                }
            }
    
            stage('Static Code Analysis by SonarQube') {
                steps {
                    script {
                            withSonarQubeEnv("aws_sonarqube") {
                            sh "${tool("sonar_scanner")}/bin/sonar-scanner \
                            -Dproject.settings=./sonar-project.properties \
                            -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

sonar-project.properties:-

```
sonar.projectKey=test-analytics
sonar.projectName=test-analytics
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.language=js
sonar.sources=.
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
# sonar.exclusions=./**/*.spec.js
sonar.tests=.
sonar.test.inclusions=./**/*.spec.js,./**/*.spec.jsx,./**/*.test.js,./**/*.test.jsx
# sonar.coverage.exclusions=./**/*.spec.js,./**/*.mock.js,node_modules/*,coverage/lcov-report/*
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=./coverage/lcov.info
# sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=test-report.xml
```

Please advise, thanks

Comment: have you found any solution for this? I 'm also facing same issue